# Extending a Cucumber step

Tags: regex, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd

I have a Cucumber step that looks like this:

```
When I enter the credentials for the user
```

and another that says

```
When I enter the correct credentials for the user
```

Corresponding step definitions are:

```
@When("I enter the ([^\"]*) for the user$")
public void stepDefinition(String cred){
    //code
}
@When("I enter the correct ([^\"]*) for the user$")
public void otherStepDefinition(String cred){
    //other code
}
```

But my second cucumber step ("I enter the correct credentials for the user") is matched by the first step definition, only with the word "correct" added to the credentials.

1. How do I fix this?
2. I'm new to regex. Would it be possible to exclude the "correct" part from the 'When' step so I could have a basic step that could be 'extended' with the "correct" part?

Comment: Try `@When("I enter the (\\S*) for the user$")` as the first rule

Comment: Change the orders.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works! Could you explain why? And post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Added an answer with some more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule should be changed to

```
@When("I enter the (\\S+) for the user$")
```

Here, `\S+` matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters. If there can be no non-whitespace chars use `\S*`.

To match two "words" you may use

```
@When("I enter the (\\S+\\s+\\S+) for the user$")
```

Note that you may control the number of "words" using quantifiers, e.g. this will match 2 or 3 words:

```
@When("I enter the (\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){1,2}) for the user$")
```

To match 2 or more words:

```
@When("I enter the (\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){1,}) for the user$")
@When("I enter the (\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)+) for the user$")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you could improve these steps and avoid the use of regex.

1) Have the user know its credentials and have the step ask the user for the credentials

So you would have

```
Given I am a user
  @user = create_user # method creates a user with credentials
end

When `I enter the users credentials` do
  fill_in username: @user.username
  fill_in password: @user.password
end

When `I enter the wrong credentials for the user` do
  fill_in username: @user.username
  fill_in password: @user.bad_password # or perhaps just bad_password
end
```

this approach removes all the complexity from cucumber and places it in the helper methods you are calling to create a user.

2) Have more arguments for your step definition

```
When 'I enter the credentials user: (\\S+) password: (\\S+) do |username, password|
  fill_in username: username
  fill_in password: password 
end

When 'I enter the bad credentials user: (\\S+) password: (\\S+) do |username, password|
  fill_in username: username
  fill_in password: password 
end
```

I strongly prefer the first approach, you should keep features and scenarios super simple and push complexity down to code. Code is much better at dealing with complexity than Cucumber.

I've been cuking since before Cucumber was named, and now never use regex's or scenario outlines when I cuke. You don't need to either.

Answer (score 2):

Several answers suggest an imperative approach which is considered an anti-pattern in BDD. Instead I strong suggest you follow the declarative approach with your Gherkin using natural or business language.  If you are actually testing the login feature, I'd propose something like:

```
When an authorised user enters their credentials
```

or role based

```
When an Administrator is authorised
```

If login is actually a prerequisite for the feature under test then something such as:

```
Given an authorised user
```

or

```
Given an authorised Administrator
```

These can be backed up with a Credentials Manager.

```
... = ExpectedData.credentialsFor("@authorised");
```

The tag should represent the characteristics, not the identity of the expected data, to be retrieved from a test data db or csv containing something like:

```
@admin, administrator, password
@authorised, user, password
@unauthorised, user, wrong
```

The same approach should be used for all test data entry, such as:

```
Given a Cash Customer
Given a Credit Customer
Given a Customer with an overdue account
```

A strong benefit of this approach is the test suit can be readily reused on different environment by making the data/credential handler environment aware.

Comment: re. 'All the existing answers are far too imperative' this will go stale very quickly as time passes and more answers are added. Perhaps 'Some of the ...' or 'Avoid imperative solutions and do something declarative' ...

Comment: @diabolist reworded alone the lines you suggest, any other feedback gratefully received.

Answer (score -1):

***Please execute below step definitions and let us know if worked for you.***

```
@When("^I enter the ([^\"]*) for the user$")
public void stepDefinition(String cred){
    //code
}
@When("^I enter the correct ([^\"]*) for the user$")
public void otherStepDefinition(String cred){
    //other code
}
```

## Without Parameter

[image: Feature File]
[image: Steps implementation]
[image: Output]

## With Parameter

[image]
[image]
[image]

*Two metacharacters (^, $) are called anchors, because they’re used to tie down each
end of the regular expression to the beginning and end of the string that they
match on.*

Comment: It is the same with the metacharacters added. How do they work? Could the problem be that the beginning and the end of the strings between them are identical?

Comment: Its working for me. Please see screen shots added in answer description.

Comment: You are not capturing the credentials parameter in the step definition pattern.

Comment: Working after adding parameters as well. Please check

Comment: The text "credentials" is to be captured in both cases. The credentials are not to be explicitly mentioned.